# PHP DateTime, parsing string date fails

Tags: php, string, date, datetime

im passing a startDate end an endDate as a get request parameter to a method,
here they get parsed like :

```
$startDate=$request->query->get('start');
$endDate=$request->query->get('end');
$logger->info('startdate is :'.$startDate.', endDate is : '.$endDate.'');

$start=new \DateTime($startDate);
$end=new \DateTime($endDate);
```

when i log those two parameters, they may be

```
startdate is: Wed Jan 12 2011 00:00:00 GMT 0100 (CET)

startDate is: Sat Jan 12 2013 00:00:00 GMT 0100 (CET)
```

so far so good, but if i log the DateTime´s instanciated from the string above it returns

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 0100-01-12 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => GMT ) 

DateTime Object ( [date] => 0100-01-15 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => GMT )
```

you can see, the DateTime does not represent the same Date

can i make a valid DateTime from those Strings ?

Update :

i tryed to use createFromFormat

like

```
    $startDate=$request->query->get('start');
    $endDate=$request->query->get('end');

    $start=new \DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d Y h:i:s e+O (T)',$startDate);
    $end=new \DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d Y h:i:s e+O (T)',$endDate);
```

but that causes exception :

```
FatalErrorException: Parse: syntax error, unexpected 'createFromFormat' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in
```

i also tryed :

```
    $start=new \DateTime(\DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d Y h:i:s e+O (T)',$startDate));
    $end=new \DateTime(\DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d Y h:i:s e+O (T)',$endDate));
```

But that creates Dates a new Date from right now ( 2014-01-21 12:28:57 )

I just dont get it right.

for any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Just for documentation, always trim your timestamps. I had a space in the end and got errors when using `DateTime::createFromFormat()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input datetime string `Wed Jan 12 2011 00:00:00 GMT 0100 (CET)` is not valid/standard for use in `DateTime()` or `strtotime()`. See `date_parse()` function to see how your datetime string is being parsed:

```php
print_r( date_parse('Wed Jan 12 2011 00:00:00 GMT 0100 (CET)') );
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/92800)</kbd>

Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat) static method to return DateTime object according to the specific format.

<kbd>[**demo**](http://eval.in/92807)</kbd>

Comment: thanks a lot, is there a way to manipulate the datestring, so it can be parsed ? unfortunatly i cant change the dateString before passing into that method, or how would the "createFromFormat()" look for my case ? sorry im a complete newbie with date´s

Comment: @johnSmith: like I said, use `DateTime::createFromFormat()`. I have also given you a demo...

Comment: hmn i really dont get it soorry

Comment: @johnSmith: You can't even copy/paste my demo? Where do you see that I create DateTime object with DateTime object as first parameter? Static method `DateTime::createFromFormat()` already creates object, if you have valid format or input, otherwise `false` is returned. **[Can you see your mistake on this demo?](https://eval.in/92917)**

Answer (score 1):

The date format you are probably using is RFC2822. As shown on the PHP date() page as this:
Thu, 21 Dec 2000 16:01:07 +0200

You switched the month and day parts and PHP was unable to determine the correct parts.

Best practice would be to either use a Unix-Timestamp (seconds after Epoch) or a better format like ISO 8601 (2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00).

Comment: hey, thanks. How can i do this ? I cant change the DateString before it comes into the method. I tryed some stuff with createFromFormat but that doesnt work, you have an idea ?

Comment: You should change this in your sending application. Can you control the sender? Maybe you give us some more Info on the sender?
I would not try to tinker with the date string before parsing it, this will only lead to more problems. Rule of thumb is, if PHP cant parse your date, you shouldnt either.