# Why does DateTime::createFromFormat() fails and returns a boolean in my second example?

Tags: php, string, datetime, format

When I run this the first one is correctly created into a date. The second one fails, returning a `boolean` and so I cannot format. Is the time out of range?

```
//works correctly
$startDate = "2015-05-06 10:49:20.637133";
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:m:s.u',$startDate);
echo $start->format('m/d/y');

//doesn't work correctly
$startDate = "2015-05-12 15:49:06.821289";
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:m:s.u',$startDate);
echo $start->format('m/d/y');
```

[<kbd>Code to reproduce the error</kbd>](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5291c1fe3c4b476f7ba7b8c771937f47f3792111)

Comment: Similar problem to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257536/php-datetime-parsing-string-date-fails but I don't believe the issue is the same

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Change the `h` to a big `H`, since the small one is 12-hours format and the big one is 24-hours format.

You can see all formats in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). And a quote from there:

> **h    12-hour format** of an hour with leading zeros  01 through 12
>   **H    24-hour format** of an hour with leading zeros  00 through 23

Means right now your code fails, because there is no 15 in the 12 hour format.

Comment: never mind the fact you have Y-m-d h:m:s ... two m's ... the second one should be i for minutes.

Answer (score 30):

Check `DateTime::getLastErrors()`:

```
php > var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:m:s',"2015-05-12 15:49:06"));
bool(false)

php > var_dump(DateTime::getLastErrors());
array(4) {
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(1)
  ["warnings"]=>
  array(1) {
    [19]=>
    string(27) "The parsed date was invalid"
  }
  ["error_count"]=>
  int(1)
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {
    [11]=>
    string(30) "Hour can not be higher than 12"
```

Comment: wow, didn't knew that the error messages from DateTime where that straightforward! ( I think the `Hour can not be higher than 12` is a pretty good hint :)

Comment: thank you for info about ```DateTime::getLastErrors()```

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the other answers, for standard formats understood by `DateTime` you don't need to create from a format:

```
$startDate = "2015-05-12 15:49:06.821289";
$start = new DateTime($startDate);
echo $start->format('m/d/y');
```