# PHP: Call to a member function format() on boolean... what

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I'm editing my controller script to make it run faster, have less lines. I have a version that works completely fine, however the modified version keeps coming up with this error, and it points to this line:

```
echo Datetime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y',$prodDate[3])->format('Y-m-d');
```

It's weird that the page will show the date, and then call the error. So the echo will run, however it says the error is on this line...

The lines before the error line:

```
$prodName = explode("@", $product['name']);
$prodDate = explode(" ",$prodName[1]);
```

So I am splitting a string to find the date. The string format goes: xxx @ yyy date. I'm exploding it to find the 'xxx', and then taking the [1] index of the exploded array, which contains 'yyy date' to find just the 'date'

When I echo out $prodDate[3], it successfully retrieves the date. Then, I want to store this date into my mysql table, so thats when I use

```
 echo Datetime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y',$prodDate[3])->format('Y-m-d');
```

I just can't find out where the problem is... the  original script (the one that works) looks similar to this and it works comletely fine

Comment: Check the output of ```$prodDate[3]``` as it seems to be causing error on that. Replace the variable with string and it works fine : ```echo Datetime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '12-23-2017')->format('Y-m-d');```

Comment: If it's showing the date and then reporting the error, the error must be on a different line from the echo.

Comment: If `$prodName[1]` contains `yyy date`, then the date should be in `$prodDate[1]`, not `$prodDate[3]`.

Comment: Yeah it outputs: "0017-08-27"

However it says the error is on THAT line o.O

Comment: prodDate[1] outputs the "y" in "yyy"
prodDate[3] outputs the actual date which is correct

Comment: Are there additional spaces in the string format that you aren't showing us? Put it in a code block so we can see the precise format.

Comment: Try breaking the statement into multiple statements. `$d = Datetime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y',$prodDate[3]); if ($d) { echo $d->format('Y-m-d'); }`

Comment: Note that you're getting the year `0017` instead of `2017` because you're using the `Y` format instead of `y` for 2-digit years.

Comment: See answer - it is due to formatting.

Comment: no extra whitespaces.

Okay sooo even though the error keeps outputting, it runs through my script and it actually adds the entry to my db with the correct date.. so weird

Comment: This code doesn't seem to have anything to do with what gets added to the DB. It's just echoing, not assigning to a variable.

Comment: I suspect you are actually inserting into the database using the $prodDate variables, but without more code, we can't really suggest answers to how it is inserting into the database right.

Comment: Please write a minimal and complete code sample (including `$product` array) which will reproduce your error. Try [rexester](http://rextester.com/ZMHV58773). Also tell us your PHP version.

Comment: Not with prodDate, I'm assigning it to $qrdate 

$qrdate =  DateTime::createFromFormat('n-j-y',$prodDate[3])->format('Y-m-d');

When I echo $qrdate, it'll echo the date of: 2017-08-27, it will add it to the table (which means the rest of my script runs) but the same error is still there

Comment: Is this a list view of products that you are generating? I am wondering if you have a rogue date somewhere, if it is.

Comment: I'm retrieving it from a list of products, so like product['name']

I just tried replacing the code with the one that worked, and now the original script which worked is producing the same error, so I'm guessing the problem is actually somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you posted that your date variable actually returns `8-27-17`

Due to this, you need to change the character definitions within the format from to be

```
n-j-y
```

Like so;

```
echo Datetime::createFromFormat('n-j-y', '8-23-17')->format('Y-m-d');
// Returns 2017-08-23
```

If you run with the incorrect format, you get the following

```
echo Datetime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '8-23-17')->format('Y-m-d'); 
// Returns 0017-08-23
```

Due to the erroneous format, the return would be `false` - meaning you are attempting to format a boolean, hence the error.

Previously been discussed on here too - top answer replicated this, for the most part.

[Why does DateTime::createFromFormat() fails and returns a boolean in my second example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30200939/why-does-datetimecreatefromformat-fails-and-returns-a-boolean-in-my-second-e)

Comment: I changed the format like you said, using 'n-j-y'

The error is still there..

however, the entry is being successfully added into the table

Comment: Then one of the variables may be incorrect. Without seeing your script as a whole, with a potential range of dates, I would just be assuming. Maybe the month is ALWAYS 2 digits? Can you confirm if a month is 0X format? Format needed, if that is so, would be ```n-m-y```. We could really do with some more dates in the range, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Note that PHP's `createFromFormat` function [returns FALSE on error](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). You might need to check whether `$prodDate[3]` truly is a date. Use `get_class` or `instanceof`.

Note further that your format is wrong.  It should be:

```
echo Datetime::createFromFormat('m-d-y',$prodDate[3])->format('Y-m-d');
```

(The first one is not "m-d-Y" it is "m-d-y")

Comment: When I echo out $prodDate[3] it says: "8-27-17"

On the original working script, the variable I use also contains "8-27-17" 

How come this one doesn't work?

Comment: Wrong format. Needs to be 08-27-2017 - else you are not using the right format variables;

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. The original working script successfully takes "8-27-17" and formats it to mysql Date, and enters it in on the table

Comment: "Y" is a full year.  "8-27-17" is not "m-d-Y".